# recurrence relations of Jacobi polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, orthogonal-polynomials

You'll commonly find recurrence relations of Jacobi polynomials in terms of $n$, $\alpha$, or $\beta$, e.g.,
$$
\begin{align*}
P_n^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x) &= c_0(x) P_{n-1}^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x) + c_1(x) P_{n-2}^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x),\\
P_n^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x) &= c_2(x) P_n^{(\alpha-1, \beta)}(x) + c_3(x) P_{n}^{(\alpha-2, \beta)}(x),\\
P_n^{(\alpha, \beta)}(x) &= c_4(x) P_n^{(\alpha, \beta-1)}(x) + c_5(x) P_{n}^{(\alpha, \beta-2)}(x).
\end{align*}
$$
I'm wondering if there are relations "around the corner" à la
$$
P_n^{(\alpha, \beta)}, P_{n+1}^{(\alpha, \beta)}, P_{n}^{(\alpha+1, \beta)}.
$$
Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

On https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08213 I found
$$
0 = (2n + \alpha + \beta)P^{(\alpha−1,\beta)}_n(x) - (n + \alpha + \beta)P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(x) + (n + \beta)P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_{n-1}(x),
$$
$$
0 = (2n + \alpha + \beta)P^{(\alpha,\beta−1)}_n(x) - (n + \alpha + \beta)P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_n(x) - (n + \alpha)P^{(\alpha,\beta)}_{n−1}(x).
$$

Comment: I do not see how this fulfills your own requirement. With relaxed conditions you may have a look at [LMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.9#ii), [Wolfram1](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/JacobiP/17/02/01/01/) or [Wolfram2](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/JacobiP/17/02/02/). I thought about posting this as answer hours ago, but they do not strictly answer the original question.